# Regex.Split on two chars

Tags: c#, regex

Input string is: `name = valu\=e;`
I want to split it with Regex to: `name` and `valu\=e;`.

So split expresion should split on char `=` which is not prefixed by `\`.

I want to keep spaces after name or before valu\=e etc. Couldn't it show here because SO trims ``.

EDIT: Input string can contains many name=value pairs. Example: `name=value;name2=value2;`.

Comment: Can the `name` also contain `=` symbols? Otherwise, it might be easier to split just by the first `=`.

Comment: Should `name\\=value` be split? If yes, how?

Comment: Sorry, I made edit, but forgot answer your question. Name cannot contain \=. Name is only a-z, A-Z, _, -.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
@"(?<!\\)="
```

`(?<!..)` is a negative lookbehind assertion and means:"not preceded by"

Heinzi question is interesting. If you choose that an even number of backslashes doesn't escape the equal sign, you must replace the pattern by:

```
@"(?<![^\\](?:\\{2})*\\)="
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Look my edit. I tried also: @"(?<!\\);" to split on ";". But it adds me an extra empty string in array. How to avoid it?

Comment: @zgnilec: If you want to use the split method you must proceed in two times. first you split with `;` and after you split each items with `=`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do like that.

Comment: @zgnilec: about the empty result, all you can do is to check if the last item is empty and remove it. (Since you don't know if there is a  `;` or not at the end.)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<name>[^=]+)=(?<value>[^;]+;)
```

then use the named groups "name" and "value" to retrieve each part separately.

e.g:

```
var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches("myInput", @"(?<name>[^=]+)=(?<value>[^;]+;)");
        foreach(Match match in matches)
        {
            var name = match.Groups["name"];
            var value = match.Groups["value"];
            doSomething(name, value);
        }
```

EDIT:

I don't know why you say it won't work, here is what I get in LinqPad using the input you gave me in the comments:

```
void Main()
{
var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(@"zenek=ben\\\;\\ek;juzek=jozek;benek2=true;krowa=-2147483648;du-pa=\\\\\\3/\\\=3\;3\;;", @"(?<name>[^=]+)=(?<value>[^;]+;)");
        foreach(Match match in matches)
        {
            var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
            var value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
            ("Name: "+name).Dump();             
            ("Value: "+value).Dump();
        }
}
```

Results:

```
Name: zenek
Value: ben\\\;
Name: \\ek;juzek
Value: jozek;
Name: benek2
Value: true;
Name: krowa
Value: -2147483648;
Name: du-pa
Value: \\\\\\3/\\\=3\;
```

Comment: This don't work correctly for me. Like Casimir said in his answer: "(?<!..) is a negative lookbehind assertion and means:"not preceded by". This would fix the problem.

Comment: @zgnilec could you give me an example of input that won't work with my solution?

Comment: `zenek=ben\\\;\\ek;juzek=jozek;benek2=true;krowa=-2147483648;du-pa=\\\\\\3/\\\=3\;3\;;` breaks at `ben\\\\`. But should not. I didn't wrote about `\;` in my post, but I thought it's analogic to everythinh which start with `\`.

Comment: Still wrong: Should be: name: zenek value: ben\\\;\\ek. Because `\;` means `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regular expressions, you might use 'regular' code. :)

```
string items = "name=value;name2 = valu= = e2";

// Split the list on items.
var itemlist = items.Split(';');
// Split each item after the first '='.
var nameValueArrayList = itemlist.Select(s => s.Split("=".ToCharArray(), 2));
// Convert the list of arrays to a dictionary
var nameValues = nameValueArrayList.ToDictionary(i => i[0], i => i[1]);

MessageBox.Show("<<<" + nameValues["name2 "] + ">>>");
```

Or in short:

```
string items = "name=value;name2 = valu= = e2";

var nameValues = items
    .Split(';')
    .Select(s => s.Split("=".ToCharArray(), 2))
    .ToDictionary(i => i[0], i => i[1]);

MessageBox.Show("<<<" + nameValues["name2 "] + ">>>");
```

I personally think that code like this is easier to maintain or pull apart and modify when the specs change. And it gives you an actual dictionary from which you can pull values by their key. 
Maybe it's possible to write this even a little shorter, but I'm still practicing with this. :)

Comment: Hmm interesting. Anyway I already used Casmir's code in my app. Thanks.